# Restrict object movement outside view

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, uitouch, restriction

I have created a `UIView` triangle object in my application.The object, i can able to drag anywhere in the screen but i want to restrict the object movement when it reaches boundary region.So that it cannot goes beyond the boundary.

How can i able to do so?

Answer (score 1):

The `UIView` triangle object's frame has a center and origin. When you move/drag the object, you must be setting this frame according to the distance calculated in `touchesMoved:` ,etc. Now all you have to do is make a check when changing the frame of your `UIView` triangle object like :

```
if((yourView.frame.origin.x + yourView.frame.bounds.x)<=320 && yourView.frame.origin.x>=0 && (yourView.frame.origin.y + yourView.frame.bounds.y)<=480 && yourView.frame.origin.y>=0)
//set your frame
else //do nothing
```